# BES IT Policy: Radio disabled after device startup?

Tags: blackberry, bes

Can anyone tell me which BES IT policy option controls the radio being disabled when the device first starts up. I have been given an IT policy which when applied to a user causes the radio on the device to be off by default when it starts up, requiring the user to activate it every time (after entering his password). When the default policy is applied this does not happen, so it is an option in the IT policy that has caused it. Does anyone know which of the options this is?

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen this when a SIM PIN code is required.  In this scenario the network will not be on at start as the SIM requires the code to be entered on the device before it starts.

Unfortunately I do not believe this is a setting on the IT policy and must be disabled on the handheld.

Disable Security at Options>Advanced Options>SIM Card

While your issue may very well be an IT policy, I wanted to share my experience with this.

Answer (score -1):

As I'm not near my own server at the moment, I'll take a stab in the dark. Are you sure it's not just low battery power on the affected Blackberries? If they don't have enough power, they won't bring up the radios when they come online.

Comment: As I said if I change between the given policy and the default policy the behaviour differs, so it has nothing to do with the battery.